# Encode HTML via Razor Helper using Nancy-classes

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

**Update: add `Nancy` using statement in pseudo-code to reflect non ASP.NET usage.**

I'm currently doing something similar to:

```cs
using Nancy.Helpers;

// ...

public static IHtmlString DoSomething<T>(this HtmlHelpers<T> helper) {
    return new NonEncodedHtmlString(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("..."));
}
```

for encoding HTML. However, passing an encoded-value to the `NonEncodedHtmlString` class feels wrong, but I don't see any other class available to do so. Is there some Nancy-specific thing I'm missing?

Note: I was expecting to find a complimentary EncodedHtmlString class which would take a string and return its encoded version.

Note 2: For no particular reason (merely personal preference at this point), I am trying to avoid using `System.Web`/`System.Web.Mvc` to handle the encoding and instead rely solely on `Nancy`-classes.

Comment: Not sure what "feels wrong" in your sample - could you please provide more concrete concerns about the code... Indeed you can use `MvcHtmlString`/`HtmlString` or your custom string too.

Comment: Updated wording of question to express my expectation of finding a complimentary class. Really just trying to determine whether I missed something in the docs. for encoding strings.

Comment: You wouldn't have been able to use the stuff in System.Web/System.Web.Mvc anyway since that's not the same IHtmlString interface as is defined in Nancy (== incompatible types)

Answer (score 0):

In Nancy:

`NonEncodedHtmlString` class would not encode the argument at instantiation.

`EncodedHtmlString` class would encode the argument at instantiation.

I agree with you that it feels a bit wrong way around.

See [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor/EncodedHtmlString.cs):

```
    public EncodedHtmlString(string value)
    {
        this.encodedValue = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value);
    }


    public NonEncodedHtmlString(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
```

Also, it is reasonable that you try to avoid using `System.Web` since Nancy targets .Net client profile and if you want to target it too.

Some may argue

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the Client Profile has been
>   discontinued and only the full redistributable package is available.

However, NET vNext Framework would desert `System.Web`... why use `System.Web` if Microsoft itself doesn't use it?